# Kotlin skiko throws ClassNotFoundException when starting the application

Tags: java, swing, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-compose

I have created a new kotlin/JVM project with IntelliJ IDEA with the `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.0"
}

group = "me.ivanefan"
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

val osName = System.getProperty("os.name")
val targetOs = when {
    osName == "Mac OS X" -> "macos"
    osName.startsWith("Win") -> "windows"
    osName.startsWith("Linux") -> "linux"
    else -> error("Unsupported OS: $osName")
}

val osArch = System.getProperty("os.arch")
var targetArch = when (osArch) {
    "x86_64", "amd64" -> "x64"
    "aarch64" -> "arm64"
    else -> error("Unsupported arch: $osArch")
}

val skikoVersion = "0.5.3"
val target = "${targetOs}-${targetArch}"
dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.skiko:skiko-jvm-runtime-$target:$skikoVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-RC")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnit()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

and I have copied the example in the README

However, after I run the main function, I got this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/GlobalScope

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 7 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

after I add `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-RC")` to the `dependencies` block in my `build.gradle.kts`, it still don't work:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/swing/SwingDispatcherKt
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.redrawer.MetalRedrawer.<init>(MetalRedrawer.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.RenderFactory_jvmKt$makeDefaultRenderFactory$1.createRedrawer(RenderFactory.jvm.kt:29)
```

Project JDK: `JDK 11.0.12 x86`

How can I solve it.

Thanks so much if you can help! :)

Comment: Did you try to add a `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-swing` dependency?

Comment: Yeah, I have worked it out! Thanks